# How to »present« in SnakeYaml?

Tags: snakeyaml

I'm trying to use SnakeYAML for stream processing of (big) YAML documents.

[image: Chart of YAML Processes] ([Context](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id859333))

Currently, I'm stuck with the »present« step. It seems that the »present« process is not available in SnakeYAML, or at least I'm unable to find it, i.e. I can parse a string to Events, but I cannot put Events back together to a string

Have I overlooked a »present« process in SnakeYAML? Or is there some third party code out there that can perform the »present« step?

I don't have enough memory to hold a full Node graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked it the first few times because the `void emit(Event)` method signature confused me:

You can perform the Present process using the `org.yaml.snakeyaml.emitter.Emitter` class.